# Return a Specific Revision of An Object

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I want to get my Envers to return the entities with the highest revision that is still below a given revision number.

What I came up with is the following:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    final Number before = AuditReaderFactory.get(this.em).getRevisionNumberForDate(new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE));

    final UserEntity user = new UserEntity().loginName("one");
    doInTransaction(() -> this.em.persist(user));

    final Number middle = AuditReaderFactory.get(this.em).getRevisionNumberForDate(new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE));

    user.setLoginName("two");
    doInTransaction(() -> this.em.persist(user));

    final Number after = AuditReaderFactory.get(this.em).getRevisionNumberForDate(new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE));

    Assert.assertEquals(new ArrayList<>(), getRevisions(before));
    Assert.assertEquals(Arrays.asList(user), getRevisions(middle));
    Assert.assertEquals(new ArrayList<>(), getRevisions(after));
}

private void doInTransaction(Runnable magic) {
    try {
        this.em.getTransaction().begin();
        magic.run();
        this.em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        this.em.getTransaction().rollback();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}   

private List<UserEntity> getRevisions(Number revisionNumber) {
    final AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(this.em);
    try {
        return auditReader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(UserEntity.class, true, false)
                .add(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().maximize().computeAggregationInInstanceContext()) // the highest revision possible
                .add(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().le(revisionNumber)) // as long as the revision is below or equal to revisionNumber
                .getResultList();
    } catch (final NoResultException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The method that does not work is `getRevisions(Object, Number)`. It returns nothing for the `before` revision (that's correct), it returns still nothing for the `middle` revision (not correct, now the entity exists!) and then returns something for the `after` revision (also not correct, the entity was deleted).

The reason for that behavior is clear when we look at the resulting SQL:

```
SELECT * from user_aud u 
    WHERE u.REV = (
        SELECT MAX (v.REV) 
            FROM user_aud v 
            WHERE v.id=u.id
        ) 
    AND u.REV <= ? ORDER BY u.REV asc
```

The `u.REV <= ?` part should be inside the inner query. The way it's generated now Hibernate decides that the max revision is 3, and then selects nothing because rev should be below 2.

I can't seem to figure out how to fix the query, and there is very little documentation on the subject. I tried removing `computeAggregationInInstanceCont()`, but there was no change in how the code behaved.

What is the correct query to get the highest revision below a user-defined value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem boiled down to setting the brackets correctly:

```
private List<UserEntity> getRevisions(Number revisionNumber) {
    final AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(this.em);
    try {
        return auditReader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(UserEntity.class, true, false)
                .add(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().maximize().computeAggregationInInstanceContext().add(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().le(revisionNumber)))
                .getResultList();
    } catch (final NoResultException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to acquire the highest revision number below a specified value as follows:

```
AuditReaderFactory.get( session )
  .createQuery()
  .forRevisionsOfEntity( EntityClass.class, true, true )
  .addOrder( AuditEntity.revisionNumber().desc() )
  .add( AuditEntity.id().eq( entityId ) )
  .add( AuditEntity.revisionNumber().le( userSuppliedValue ) )
  .setMaxResults( 1 )
  .singleResult();
```

This will order all revisions in descending order and returns the first entry.  The rows in the result set will be for `EntityClass` entity with primary key `entityId` and applies the restriction that the the entities had to be audited with a revision number less-than or equal-to the supplied value.

Comment: Okay, that works for exactly one result. In practice we have many entities returned by the method (hence the list). Do you have any idea what to do then?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you'd have multiple values returned in a list.  If you're specifying both a single entity type and a primary key (as in your example), then only "list" that makes sense is all revisions of that entity.  So instead, you want the maximum revision for all entity type/primary key pair that is less-than or equal-to a supplied revision value?

Comment: Yes, adding the ID was wrong. I did not realize how much it would change the question (and hence the answer) when creating a simple example. I changed the question accordingly. We want to return a "snapshot" of how the table looked at the specific revision number.